# How to prevent vim from highlighting empty spaces?

Tags: vim, windows-subsystem-for-linux, syntax-highlighting

I'm not sure if this is a vim problem or command prompt. I am using WSL to ssh to a remote machine (centos).

I'm using vim to edit source code from the remote machine. When I load the source code, it looks fine. But when I scroll down and then scroll back up again all the text that was out of the screen when I scroll down gets a weird hilight.

[image]

Comment: Try to use any terminal emulator like mintty or ConEmu etc and check if the same issue occurs.

Comment: What terminal are you using? Just ubuntu.exe?

Comment: yes just ubuntu.exe

Comment: still doesn't solve the issue but it turns out when I do set background=dark all the highlight goes away. Note that my .vimrc has set background=dark.

Comment: @Biswapriyo, I tried conemu, but when using ConEmu, when I ssh to a remote computer and use vim to edit source code, it doesn't give me syntax coloring. I think that could be a separate discussion. For now, I think I'll stick to WSL's ubuntu.exe